# Flutter: Running/Debugging app -> Black screen and Could not wrap onscreen surface Android Emulator

Tags: android, flutter

Got the latest & greatest Flutter & I'm seeing a black screen on my Android emulator and the following errors in the console.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
E/flutter ( 4538): [ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(161)] Could not wrap onscreen surface.
E/flutter ( 4538): [ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(161)] Could not wrap onscreen surface.
I/chatty  ( 4538): uid=10086(u0_a86) gpu_thread identical 50 lines
```

Flutter doctor results:

```
[✓] Flutter (on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G29, locale en-US, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at /Users/michaelrtraverso/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision bbcfb8d51a (6 days ago), 2017-08-01 14:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision f2af347363
    • Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/michaelrtraverso/dev/android-sdk-macosx
    • Platform android-26, build-tools 26.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/michaelrtraverso/dev/android-sdk-macosx
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 8.3.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 8.3.3, Build version 8E3004b
    • ios-deploy 1.9.1
    • CocoaPods version 1.2.1

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-884-b01)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.2)
    • Flutter plugin version 15.2
    • Dart plugin version 172.3317.48

[✓]  Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android O (API 25) (emulator)
```

Answer (score -1):

OK so it's not a fix but the latest Flutter build in the alpha channel seems busted. Switching to the master channel brings Android apps back to life. In your terminal:

`flutter channel master`

then re-run and you should be able to be back in business.

Comment: The latest release seems to have fixed it.